# Sharepoint online:I can't see 'share' button, when granting permissions on a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

Can anyone help please?

I'm trying to grant permissions to "group 1", to be able to have "read" permissions level, on a specific 'page 1"

So, I follow the following steps:

1. Go to page 1 -> click "edit" -> on the 'page' tab : "Page permissions" -> "Stop inheriting permissions"
2. I click on " grant permissions" button -> I select the group of people to "invite people", then go to "show options" and select " Read" on the "select permission level " combo.
3. Then I only see a 'cancel' button, but no "share' button.

I've checked the 'allow access sharing" option is enabled,  (knowing that I have full control on it), I really don't understand why I'm not able to see the 'share' button.

Help please, any idea/suggestion is more than welcomed.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In case this may help someone else in the same situation:
Surprisingly, I've changed the browser and it worked. The 'share" button appeared.

Comment: Unbelievable, been struggling with this forever. Button is hidden in Chrome, but works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, if you have Adblocker for Chrome - NoAds, then disable it or turn it off on the SharePoint domain.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Chrome, but in my case disabling the add blocker resolved this, after that I was able to see the Share button in Chrome :).