# Unable to find share button on Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using sharepoint online (office 365). I created a survey on a subsite and I wanted to share the survey. However I do not see any share button on the page that allows me to share my survey. I've tried other methods online such as [using other browsers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163516/sharepoint-onlinei-cant-see-share-button-when-granting-permissions-on-a-pag) and enabling site permissions for 'following content' & 'getting started' as shown in this picture: [image]

However I am still unable to see the share button to share my survey:
[image]

On the main site, I could however see the share button. [image]. This is quite baffling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is no Share button in a survey list by design.

If you want to share survey list with other users, you can click Settings->Survey settings->permissions for this survey, grant specific users with relevant permission.

Comment: Hi, I made changes to my post, to inform readers that i can only see the share button on my main site, but not my sub site.

Comment: what's the site you used? whether it's a modern team site? per my test, the modern team site has no Share button by default. Besides, the share button on the navigation bar is for sharing a site not a survey.